# Tkinter Checkboxes to change lookup command

Tags: python, tkinter, dsquery

hoping someone can help me.  I have the working code below that creates a UI for looking up the name of an AD user and Looking up a users AD Groups.
It all works fine as IS.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import subprocess
import requests
import urllib3
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
#Get Username
def button_get_user():
    USERID = info.get()
    name = subprocess.check_output(
        'net user' + " " + USERID + " " + '/domain | FIND /I "Full Name"', shell=True
    )
    full_name = name.replace(b"Full Name", b"").strip()
    print_out.delete("1.0", "end")
    print_out.insert("end-1c",full_name.decode())

#Get Group Info
def button_get_group():
    USERID = info.get()
    group = subprocess.check_output(
        'dsquery user -name' + " " + USERID + " " + '| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid', shell=True
    )
    print_out.delete("1.0", "end")
    print_out.insert("end-1c",group.decode())


#GUI SECTION
#WINDOW PARAMETERS
root = Tk()
root.title("Steve's Network Tool")
#root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
root.geometry("550x550")
root.resizable(False, False)

#WINDOW MENU OPTIONS
def about():
    messagebox.showinfo('Version History', 'Version 1.0 Test Edition')

menubar = Menu(root)
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
file.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
help = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
help.add_command(label="About", command=about)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)


#INPUT FIELDS - PASSWORD CHARACTERS REPLACED WITH '*'
#LEFT FRAME
frame0 = Frame(root)
frame0.grid(row=1)
tkinter.Label(frame0, text="Enter Input:").grid(row=1)

info = tkinter.Entry(frame0)
info.grid(row=1, column=1)

root_label = tkinter.Label(frame0, text="AD Tasks:", pady=20)
root_label.grid(row=1, column=3)

#GET USERNAME INFO
button_get_info = Button(frame0, text="Username", command=button_get_user)
button_get_info.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=0)
#GET GROUP INFO
button_get_info = Button(frame0, text="Group List", command=button_get_group)
button_get_info.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=0)
#DOMAIN CHOICE
var1 = IntVar()
euprod_checkbutton = Checkbutton(frame0, text="Domain1", variable=var1)
euprod_checkbutton.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
prod_checkbutton = Checkbutton(frame0, text="Domain2", variable=var2)
prod_checkbutton.grid(row=1, column=7, sticky=W)

#ACTION BUTTONS & OUTPUT WINDOW
#FRAME3
frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid(row=9, pady=10)

#OUTPUT WINDOW
print_out = ScrolledText(frame3, height=20, width=50, bg="Black", fg='yellow')
print_out.grid(row=3, column=1)

#Copy Text Button
# triggered off left button click on text_field
def copy_text_to_clipboard():
    #root.clipboard_clear()  # clear clipboard contents
    root.clipboard_append(print_out.get("end-1c", info))  # append new value to clipboard

#COPY TO CLIPBOARD BUTTON
button_copy = Button(frame3, text="Copy To Clipboard", command=copy_text_to_clipboard)
button_copy.grid(row=11, column=1)

#CLEAR OUTPUT WINDOW
def clear():
    print_out.delete("1.0","end")
button_copy = Button(frame3,text="Clear Output", command=clear)
button_copy.grid(row=12, column=1)

#EXIT PROGRAM BUTTON
button_quit = Button(frame3, text="Exit", command=root.quit, padx=20)
button_quit.grid(row=13, column=1)


root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

The check boxes currently are in active.
What I would like to do is manipulate this section:

```
#Get Group Info
def button_get_group():
    USERID = info.get()
    group = subprocess.check_output(
        'dsquery user -name' + " " + USERID + " " + '| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid', shell=True
            )
```

If Domain 1 is ticked change

```
'dsquery user -name' + " " + USERID + " " + '| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid'
```

to

```
'dsquery user -name -d Domain1' + " " + USERID + " " + '| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid'
```

If Domain 2 is ticked change

```
'dsquery user -name' + " " + USERID + " " + '| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid'
```

to

```
'dsquery user -name -d Domain2' + " " + USERID + " " + '| dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid'
```

Hope this makes sense.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which domain will be used if both "Domain1" and "Domain2" are checked?

Comment: Yes this is something I didn't consider.  Which is why the use of radio buttons below was a much better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situation where you have two or more mutually exclusive options (i.e., only one thing can be selected at a time) it's better to use a group of radio buttons instead of check boxes.

Here's an example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


#Get Group Info
def button_get_group():
    USERID = info.get()
    domain = radio_var.get()
    # PRO TIP: f-strings are your friend here!
    group = subprocess.check_output(
        f'dsquery user -name {USERID}{domain} | dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid',
        shell=True
    )


root = tk.Tk()
# create a variable to store the selection, give it a default value of '' (empty string)
radio_var = tk.StringVar(root, '')

option_none = ttk.RadioButton(
    root,
    text='None',  # text shown on the GUI
    value='',  # the value this option has
    variable=radio_var,  # bind the StringVar
)
option_none.pack()

option_one = ttk.RadioButton(
    root,
    text='Domain1',  # text shown on the GUI
    value=' -d Domain1',  # the value this option has
    variable=radio_var,  # bind the StringVar
)
option_one.pack()

option_two = ttk.RadioButton(
    root,
    text='Domain2',  # text shown on the GUI
    value=' -d Domain2',  # the value this option has
    variable=radio_var,  # bind the StringVar
)
option_two.pack()

...  # code omitted for brevity

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can you clear selection of those radiobuttons?

Comment: I assumed the inclusion of a 'None' option met this need.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Note that the command should be `f'dsquery user -name {USERID} {domain} ...'` according to the help of `dsquery`.

Comment: @acw1668 Good catch - I'll swap those quick!